# CSS How i set on body without wrappers three background images

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

#### Aim:

I need to create a solution with an index that have three background images.
`The first` that takes the entire screen, `the second` that takes the left half of screen and `the third` that takes the right half of screen.

#### Problem:

everything i trying goes to nowhere.

Tanks.

Comment: first show us what you would like, a sketch perhaps.  Then show us the code you tried and what problems you are having

Comment: Can you please show what you have already done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple background images on one element, and control them with comma separated lines.

See the example below.

**More about multiple backgrounds:**

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

```css
body {
  background-image: 
    url('https://placehold.it/100x100/09f/fff'),
    url('https://placehold.it/200x200/0df/fff'), 
    url('https://placehold.it/1200x1200/000/fff');
  background-position: 
    center left, 
    center right,
    center center;
  background-size: 
    auto, 
    auto, 
    cover;
  background-repeat: 
    no-repeat, 
    no-repeat, 
    no-repeat;
  
  /* not related to this issue*/
  height: 100vh;
}
```